# How to give a real iPhone null locale

Tags: ios, objective-c, locale

I have an iOS app that gets the country code like this

```
NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
```

I understand that technically this can be null, but I assumed (incorrectly) that this could only occur in corner cases where it wouldn't matter.

But now I have a user whose phone is reporting null locale and it's breaking a part of my app so that they can't use it. While working on a bug fix, I just want to understand how to get into and out of this state, so that they can work around the bug. But even when they set their language and region to English/USA, they still get this weird result on the Language & Region screen:

[image: unknown currency sign]

and the bug in my app still occurs due to null locale/region. That's 0xa4 "currency sign" at the bottom, according to Wikipedia:

> The currency sign ¤ is a character used to denote an unspecified currency.

So it seems that even iOS does not understand their locale. How does this happen with a real phone and how do you fix it?

They're using an iPhone 12 mini on iOS 14.7.1.

Comment: "even when they set their language and region to English/USA" I doubt it. There is no such thing as English/USA language or region. I don't know how the current locale can be null, but I would suggest that something is deeply wrong with this user's device.

Comment: Did you ask them which region they were setting?

Comment: @matt added full screenshot. You can see that the language is English and the region is United States

Comment: @PtitXav I'm not sure what the original settings were, but the full screenshot is after I asked them to change it to English/US in the hopes it would fix it

Comment: Well, you have to ask yourself how that's possible. I can't make my phone look like that. Maybe it's been jailborked or otherwise interfered with.

Comment: @matt Not necessarily. Typing up a (long) answer now

Comment: Cool! This will be educational

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unfortunate and somewhat rare bug that appears to be related to user preferences getting smashed on-device, and without a known cause, there isn't much you can do about it short of attempting to detect it and falling back to some default locale (like `en_US`).

Digging in (details from Hopper):

- *<Foundation>* `+[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale]` creates an instance of `NSAutoLocale`, an instance of a private class whose initializer fetches `+[NSLocale currentLocale]` and listens to a privately-defined notification for when the current locale changes:

  ```
                       +[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale]:
  00000000000bdfd8         stp        x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!                     ; Objective C Implementation defined at 0x24fb80 (class method)
  00000000000bdfdc         mov        x29, sp
  00000000000bdfe0         adrp       x8, #0x353000                               ; &@selector(variantFormatter)
  00000000000bdfe4         ldr        x0, [x8, #0xf58]                            ; objc_cls_ref_NSAutoLocale,_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoLocale
  00000000000bdfe8         bl         imp___stubs__objc_opt_new                   ; objc_opt_new
  00000000000bdfec         ldp        x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
  00000000000bdff0         b          imp___stubs__objc_autorelease               ; objc_autorelease

  int -[NSAutoLocale _init](int arg0) {
      r19 = arg0;
      r0 = [NSLocale currentLocale];
      r0 = [r0 retain];
      r8 = 0x35603c;
      asm { ldpsw      x8, x9, [x8] };
      *(r19 + r9) = r0;
      pthread_mutex_init(r19 + r8, 0x0);
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:r19 selector:@selector(_update:) name:@"kCFLocaleCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification-4" object:0x0];
      r0 = r19;
      return r0;
  }
  ```

  `NSAutoLocale` responds to all locale methods and forwards them to the underlying `NSLocale` instance, so we can look to see what `+currentLocale` returns
- *<CoreFoundation>* `+[NSLocale currentLocale]` simply returns the results of `_CFLocaleCopyCurrent()` (`NSLocale` and `CFLocaleRef` are toll-free bridged):

  ```
  void +[NSLocale currentLocale]() {
      [_CFLocaleCopyCurrent() autorelease];
      return;
  }
  ```

  `_CFLocaleCopyCurrent()` returns the contents of a shared implementation of a "Guts" function which is called from multiple places with different parameters:

  ```
  int _CFLocaleCopyCurrent() {
      rax = __CFLocaleCopyCurrentGuts(0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0);
      return rax;
  }
  ```
- *<CoreFoundation>* `__CFLocaleCopyCurrentGuts` is too large to include here inline, but when called with the given parameters (and when it has no cached "current locale" instance), it creates a new locale by looking up the value for the `AppleLocale` key from current user preferences

  - Failing that, it also looks up the `AppleLanguages` dictionary and tries to create a locale from one of the values, but that's separate

So effectively, the "current locale" is simply a locale object constructed with the locale identifier defined by "AppleLocale" in prefs. The specific location looked at is the `kCFPreferencesAnyApplication` application (i.e., global prefs) for the `kCFPreferencesCurrentUser` at the `kCFPreferencesCurrentHost` — i.e., what is returned by `defaults read/write NSGlobalDomain ...` (equivalent to `defaults read/write -g ...`).

You can inspect this value yourself, and because my machine is set to English in the United States, I see

```
$ defaults read -g AppleLocale
en_US
```

You can write a small tool that inspects "AppleLocale", write a value to "AppleLocale", and rerun it to inspect the change if you'd like, but this is also possible to do in-process (in a sort of convoluted way). If you forward-declare `_CFLocaleResetCurrent()` from Objective-C somewhere (a bridging header will work), you can directly call the function which clears the current locale cache, and by manipulating `CFPreferences` directly, see the changes to the current locale:

```
import Foundation

func overwriteLocaleIdentifier(_ identifier: String) {
    // We use kCFPreferencesCurrentApplication to avoid changing system-wide settings.
    CFPreferencesSetAppValue("AppleLocale" as CFString, identifier as CFString, kCFPreferencesCurrentApplication)
    _CFLocaleResetCurrent()
}

func withOverwrittenLocaleIdentifier(_ identifier: String, _ action: () -> Void) {
    let currentIdentifier = Locale.current.identifier
    defer { overwriteLocaleIdentifier(currentIdentifier) }

    overwriteLocaleIdentifier(identifier)
    action()
}

print(Locale.current.identifier)
withOverwrittenLocaleIdentifier("he_IL") {
    print(Locale.current.identifier)
}

print(Locale.current.identifier)
```

For me, this produces

```
en_US
he_IL
en_US
```

For better or worse, this behavior means that whatever value is found for the "AppleLocale" key is what will get used as the current locale identifier.

If the "AppleLocale" value is *missing*, you'll start seeing some logs:

```
2021-09-15 16:47:52.013846-0400 LocaleExample[40427:9913027] [User Defaults] CFPrefsPlistSource<0x107b08420> (Domain: kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No): Value for key AppleLocale was (null). Expected en_US (defaults(40182): 2021-09-15 16:44:29 (EDT))
```

When either the locale identifier is missing (or set to nonsense), the system can absolutely start misbehaving, since the locale identifier is used directly.

---

So, when can this happen? On a typical iOS device, the answer *should* be "never", but this is not the case. Through typical UI, there is no way to accidentally set the locale identifier to something invalid, but I've seen in the wild user's locales set to `""`, `"en"` (no country code), or simply missing, on devices in hand, confirmed to be stock, not jailbroken, etc. All it *really* takes is one misbehaving process to clobber the "AppleLocale" value and you can end up in this situation.

There's typically no real recourse beside falling back to a known good local (or a default like `en_US`), and if a user asks, request that they reset their locale through Settings (changing the settings, then changing back). Ideally, this will get them back to a known good state.

Comment: I will add that while writing this answer, I did discover that it appears on macOS 11.5.2 that `cfprefsd` (the daemon in charge of user preferences) now appears to "protect" the `AppleLocale` key so it can't be outright deleted. (See `_isSpecialKey` in CoreFoundation) You can still set it to garbage, but it's a bit more difficult to trigger the failure condition directly

Comment: To add to this, I suggest that either the end user (preferably) or the developer submit a bug report to Apple's Bug Radar.

Comment: It can't hurt, though I will say that once the value is clobbered, it's pretty much impossible to figure out how or why. But, maybe `_isSpecialKey` is helping diagnose the issue internally — it's possible internal builds have additional logging around this to help catch misbehaving processes.

Comment: Yeah. Is there anything the end user can do to fix the bug? Depending on how understanding the end-user is, OP may wish to say something like: "This is a bug in the iOS operating system (and therefore not my problem). Here's how to fix it: (Update iOS, reset phone to factory default, etc.)"

Comment: Yep! That's the callout at the end — the user should go to Settings, change their locale (even reordering languages in the list should trigger a locale update) and change back.

Comment: @ItaiFerber that's what I suggested and they claimed it didn't fix it. I'm hoping they just did the locale update incorrectly (somehow). The screenshot in my question is after they tried to change it and, based on the currency symbol, the locale is still bad. Beats me

Comment: @Max Yeah, without knowing exactly what steps they took, it's impossible from our end to know. Either way, hopefully it's clear to the user (based on the Settings screen itself) that it's not an issue with your app, but something with their system.